# Durandal, Socket.io and require

Tags: sockets, socket.io, require, durandal

I'm having a hard time setting up Durandal to include the socket io library.

I've tried a few methods, including the path in the main.js library but as it isn't a single js file, it has never worked.

If anyone has experience with this, I'd extremely appreciate it!!

Thanks

Edited with code,

```
requirejs.config({
paths: {
    'text': '../lib/require/text',
    'durandal':'../lib/durandal/js',
    'plugins' : '../lib/durandal/js/plugins',
    'transitions' : '../lib/durandal/js/transitions',
    'knockout': '../lib/knockout/knockout-3.1.0',
    'bootstrap': '../lib/bootstrap/js/bootstrap',
    'jquery': '../lib/jquery/jquery-1.9.1',
    'toastr' : '../lib/toastr/toastr',
    'moment' : '../lib/moment/moment',
    'when' : '../lib/when/when',
    'flipclock': '../lib/flipclock/flipclock',
    'require': '../lib/require/require'
},
shim: {
    'bootstrap': {
        deps: ['jquery'],
        exports: 'jQuery'
   }
}
```

});

```
  define(['durandal/system', 'durandal/app', 'durandal/viewLocator', 'require',         'plugins/http'],  function (system, app, viewLocator, require, http) {


var io = require('socket.io')(http);
```

Comment: Can you please show some of your code?

Comment: I've edited my post with a snippet with a few unrelated lines of code removed.  I've also tried including socket.io in paths, and as a shim.  Which I assume I either did wrong, or that isn't the correct method

Answer (score 3):

In order to work you need to add socket.io to the paths config, as well as define a shim.
Make sure the path to socket io is setup properly.

```
paths: {
    ....
    'socketio': 'PATH_TO/socket.io/socket.io'
},
shim: {
   'socketio': {
    'exports': 'io'
   }
}

define(['durandal/system', 'durandal/app', 'durandal/viewLocator', 'bootstrap',
        'socketio', 'knockout'],
function (system, app, viewLocator, bootstrap, io, ko) {
  // if its on the same host
  var testsocket = io.connect(window.location.hostname);

  // otherwhise
  var testsocket = io.connect(PATHTOSOCKET);
});
```

that should do the trick

EDIT:
Additionally it seems like you want to use the NPM package in the frontend, which is clearly not the way to go. Socket.IO creates a frontend proxy, which can be utilized the way described above.

Comment: I'll try that when I get a chance, will let you know if it works

Comment: That worked! I wish I could up vote your answer.  Need more rep.  I'm so grateful thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to include `socket.io` in your requirejs configuration:

```
requirejs.config({
    paths: {
        ...,
        'socket': 'path/to/socket.io'
    },
 ...
});
```

Then, you can access the library from within your application like such:

```
define([..., 'socket'],  
function (..., socket) {
    // body here with access to socket
    socket.doSomething();
});
```

Comment: I still have a few issues. I've answered my question with my updated code and error

Answer (score 0):

```
  paths: {
    'text': '../lib/require/text',
    'durandal':'../lib/durandal/js',
    'plugins' : '../lib/durandal/js/plugins',
    'transitions' : '../lib/durandal/js/transitions',
    'knockout': '../lib/knockout/knockout-3.1.0',
    'bootstrap': '../lib/bootstrap/js/bootstrap',
    'jquery': '../lib/jquery/jquery-1.9.1',
    'toastr' : '../lib/toastr/toastr',
    'moment' : '../lib/moment/moment',
    'when' : '../lib/when/when',
    'flipclock': '../lib/flipclock/flipclock',
    'require': '../lib/require/require',
    'socket': '../lib/socket.io/lib/socket'
},
```

So I've included it in my requirejs configuration.

```
 define(['durandal/system', 'durandal/app', 'durandal/viewLocator', 'require', 'plugins/http', 'socket'],  function (system, app, viewLocator, require, http, socket) {
```

This seems to have help but now I'm getting,

```
Module name "events" has not been loaded yet for context: _. Use require([]) exception
```

.  The page does load now, but I assume I must include "events" too?

The issues seems to be the standard require for socket io is something like this,

var io = require('socket.io')(http);

Which must resolve all the dependencies as the npm socket.io has modules within it.  The requirejs path similar loads a single js file, were socket.io has many.